# StageWebView wont dispose()

Tags: actionscript-3

```
swv.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, swvLocationChange);
            swv.viewPort = null;
            swv.stage = null;
            swv.dispose();
            swv = null;
```

This is the code that I have to remove the stagewebview. Following previous articles and other stackoverflow posts, it will not go away. I still see a leftover white screen. What do I do? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Your code is correct, that's the one I have been using for years. Which version of Adobe AIR are you using?

Comment: 23.0 for Android and iOS. Running debugging on Android 5.1